Omni-Channel loaded event
On opening SF console app, I need to login to omni-channel with specific status (in an aura component on utility bar). Now it just tries to login and fails a few times with 'Omni-Channel is not available', because it's not loaded yet. On error, setTimeout is used to try again.
I thought there had to be a better way. But I haven't found any event or anything, that would  notify that omni-channel has finished loading or is ready to use.
I tried using getServicePresenceStatusId, but same error.
In setup I didn't find anything helpful.
Is there a way to check, if omni-channel is ready to login? Or maybe completely different approach to automatically login with certain status?
